# What does the little lock beside NetStandard.library (2.0.3) mean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-standard-2.0

I have a .net standard 2.0 project and I just noticed a lock icon.
What does it mean?

[image: lock icon]

[image: and this]

[image: right click]

[Update]

I noticed the lock on a 4.7.2 test project.
When I upgraded to 4.8 the lock went away

Comment: I don't know, but if I had to guess out of the blue based on my domain knowledge of locks, I think it would mean you're not allowed to remove this package, unlike the other ones (since then it wouldn't be much of a .NET Standard project anymore).

Comment: In support of @JeroenMostert's guess, note that there's no 'Remove' option if you right-click that package (for the same obvious reason), and there is with the other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The little lock beside NetStandard.Library(2.0.3) means this package is impliclity defined from your TargetFramework.

If you want to change the setting of NetStandard.library, you can refer to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/net-standard?tabs=windows#editing-net-standard-library-settings-1).